# Resize a gridview's image with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am new in jquery and stuck in somewhere. I have a gridview and have an image column in it. Trying resize these images but really can't figure it out. Tried this code and it works well when images are not in a gridview, but like I said I need to work it out within a gridview.

Here is my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFuel" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceFuels">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sürücü">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#GetDriverNameAndSurname(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("DriverId"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Araç">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#GetCarPlate(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("CarId"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fiş">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("FuelPrice") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mGrid img').each(function () {
            var maxWidth = 151; // Max width for the image
            var maxHeight = 151;    // Max height for the image
            var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
            var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
            var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

            // Check if the current width is larger than the max
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
                $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
                $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
                height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
                width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            }

            // Check if current height is larger than max
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
                $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
                width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I make it work with my gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try looping through each cell.  If an image exists then do your ratio.

$('.mGrid tr').each(function () {

```
$('td', this).each(function () {

    //check if image exists

 });
```

})

Comment: Like I said I am new in jquery so it would be awesome if you could show how should I check a td if it is image or not ?

Comment: After looping through each cell you need to check if an image exists. I didn't test it myself but it should be something like the following: var img = $(this).find('img'); if (img.length > ) { // do the ratio to the img }